# Can the views of a fragment be modified when the fragment is in backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments which share the same spot on a activity. When activity starts `fragA` is displayed. When you click a button from `fragA` it gets pushed to backstack and replaced by `fragB`. When a button from `fragB` is pressed the `fragB` is destroyed and `fragA` is poped from the backstack but it should also change some views based on what button from fragB was pressed (set the text for a textview for example). I used interfaces for fragment-activity communication. Everything goes well but the views from fragA don't want to change. I think I'm trying to change them while the fragment is in backstack.

```
@Override
    public void onFragBClick(Bundle bundle) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragA = (FragA) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAG_A);
        if (fragA != null) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(TAG_FRAG_A_BACKSTACK, 
                    FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            fragA.onFragBSignalReceived(bundle);
        }

    }
```

This is the method that handles communication. Everything seems fine in logs, `onFragBSignalReceived` gets called, but I can't change the state of `fragA`'s views in it. My guess is that when it gets called `fragA` is still on the backstack and that's why views are not updated. In that case how can I achieve this behavior in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [popBackStackImmediate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStackImmediate%28int,%20int%29) instead of popBackStack(). popBackStackImmediate() will perform the operation inside the method, whereas popBackStack() will queue the action and perform it later on.